# Function containing both a square cube

Tags: python

I've tried solving the below challenge

```
sq_cube([50/2, 40/3, 30/4, 20/5, 10/6]) == [[64, 512], [16, 64], [4, 8]]
```

This is the code used and somehow it returns a blank list `[]` instead of `[[64, 512], [16, 64], [4, 8]]`

```
def sq_cube(numbers):
    return [[round(num ** 2), round(num ** 3)] for num in numbers if num % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Try `return [[64, 512], [16, 64], [4, 8]]`.

Comment: Looks like this belongs on [puzzling.se].

Comment: What is the purpose of your calculations? Like, what are the boundaries of your problem? Just looking at 3 lines of codes is pretty much unclear where you want go and how...

Comment: "it returns a blank list []" - Not true. It returns [[16, 64]].

Comment: Looks like you want a list of lists where the sublists are [x\*\*2, x\*\*3] Thus, if one such element needs to be [64, 512] then x needs to be 8. None of the values in the input list are equal to 8

Comment: I interpret the question as a challenge found somewhere or provided by an instructor. The challenge is to develop a function that uses a list comprehension such that `sq_cube([50/2, 40/3, 30/4, 20/5, 10/6]) == [[64, 512], [16, 64], [4, 8]]` is `True`.  Based on this interpretation, I provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in line.

```
def sq_cube(numbers):
    # Note  input [50 / 2, 40 / 3, 30 / 4, 20 / 5, 10 / 6]
    # becomes numbers = [25.0, 13.333333333333334, 7.5, 4.0, 1.6666666666666667]
    # only 4.0 is processed.
    print(f'{numbers=}\n')
    return [[round(num ** 2), round(num ** 3)] for num in numbers if
            num % 2 == 0]


print(f'{sq_cube([50 / 2, 40 / 3, 30 / 4, 20 / 5, 10 / 6])=}\n')


def sq_cube_b(numbers):
    """
    Notice the new positions of the round() function.
    Also, round(num) for the if test.
    was:
    return [[round(num ** 2), round(num ** 3)] for num in numbers if
            num % 2 == 0]
    Now is:
    """
    return [[round(num) ** 2, round(num) ** 3] for num in numbers if
            round(num) % 2 == 0]


print(f'{sq_cube_b([50 / 2, 40 / 3, 30 / 4, 20 / 5, 10 / 6])=}\n')
```